# NodeJS Express with Observables example

Tags: node.js, express, observable

I have ben searching on google, but haven't ben able to find examples for how to use Observables with **Express** for Async programming. If anyone could provide some examples, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: may i know what you want to achieve using observables

Comment: Basically, I want to use observables with Mongoose, and any one async operations i perform